# c# web app - allow client to FTP entire folder

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have a **c# webapp** that I need to allow users **to upload an entire folder** and it's contents to the server.  I have code that **only works when testing locally**, because it's *searching all contents of the local directory and uploads*.

I'm not sure how to keep this working when I deploy the app to the server. Soes anybody know of an **example of a web interface that allows you to upload an entire folder at once**?

```
private void uploadWebsite(string dirPath, string uploadPath, string imagesPath)
{
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*");
     string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath);

     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         ftpClient.upload(uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
         if (file.Contains(".jpg") || file.Contains(".png") || file.Contains(".gif"))
             ftpClient.upload(uploadPath + "/images/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
     }

     foreach (string subDir in subDirs)
     {
         ftpClient.createDirectory(uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(subDir));
         uploadWebsite(subDir, uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(subDir), null);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a usable end user experience you'll have to rely on Flash to provide upload controls. Something like this:

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/

This comes down to presenting the end user with a means to select multiple items at once. The code on the back end changes dramatically as well, since you'll be dealing with an array of file uploads.

Maintaining the directory structure may be a problem as well; IIRC [most/all?] browsers only supply filenames when transmitting data with multipart/form-data.

You should consider if requiring the end user to create a zip file - thus requiring only a single file chosen for upload, and retaining directory structure - may be a better solution for this problem.

Comment: If you are going to so so far as to use a plugin, like flash, It might be a better to just implement an ftp client in said plugin see here http://maliboo.pl/projects/FlexFTP/.  Of course you could do the same in any plugin platform